# Dealing with a Sequence of Sets with Two Indices and Simple Function based on that Sequence of Sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, simple-functions

Okay so I have a measurable function $f$ and a set $E_{n,i}$
$$E_{n,i}=\left\{ x:\frac{i-1}{2^{n}} \leq f(x)<\frac{i}{2^{n}}\right\}$$ 
where $i=1,...,n2^{n}$ and $n=1,2,...$

Then I have another set $A_{n}$ given by
$$
A_{n}=\{x:f(x)\geq n\}
$$
and then I have a sequence of functions $s_{n}$ given by
$$
s_{n}=\sum^{n2^{n}}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{2^{n}} \mathbb{1}_{E_{n,i}} +n\mathbb{1}_{A_{n}}
$$
So I'm slightly unsure about whether my approach to evaluate this is correct. My instincts tell me to first fix $n$ and then work from there. Say $n=4$ then we would have
$$
s_{4}=\sum^{4(2^{4})}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{2^{4}} \mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}} +4\mathbb{1}_{A_{4}}$$
which then gives us
$$
s_{4}=\sum^{64}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{16} \mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}} +4\mathbb{1}_{A_{4}}$$
and I feel pretty confident that is correct but I have no one to verify this. Obviously it would be pretty ridiculous to try and do this by hand but just to get the idea of a few of the sets $E_{4,i}$ I have
$$E_{4,1}=\left\{ x:0 \leq f(x)<\frac{1}{16}\right\}$$
and then 
$$
E_{4,2}=\left\{ x:\frac{1}{16} \leq f(x)<\frac{2}{16}\right\}$$
and
$$E_{4,3}=\left\{ x:\frac{2}{16} \leq f(x)<\frac{3}{16}\right\}$$ 
and finally
$$E_{4,64}=\left\{ x:\frac{63}{16} \leq f(x)<\frac{64}{16}\right\}$$ 
so clearly 
$$
\bigcup^{64}_{i=1} E_{4,i}=\{x:f(x)<4\}
$$
which makes sense since it seems that the whole point of the sets $E_{n,i}$ is to cover $[0,n)$ in the sense that
$$
\bigcup^{n2^{n}}_{i=1} E_{n,i} \subseteq \{x:f(x)<n\}
$$
Now here is the part I think I have messed up on:
$$\int s_{4} d\mu=126 \, \mu(\{x:f(x)<4\})+4 \, \mu(\{x:f(x)\geq 4\})$$
where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and the 126 comes from
$$
\sum^{64}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{16}=126$$
at least according to MuPad and the additive property of the Lebesgue measure for disjoint sets implies that
$$
\sum^{64}_{i=1} \mu(E_{4,i})=\mu\left(\bigcup^{64}_{i=1} E_{4,i} \right)
$$
and we can treat the sum
$$
\sum^{64}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{16}
$$
as a constant with respect to the integration
$$\int s_{4} d\mu$$
which allows us to write
$$
\int s_{4} d\mu=\sum^{64}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{16} \int \sum^{64}_{i=1} \mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}} \, d\mu+4\int \mathbb{1}_{A_{4}} d\mu
$$
and I think that last part in treating the summation as a constant might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct all the way up until the last equation, which should be:
$$
\int s_{4} d\mu=\sum^{64}_{i=1} \frac{i-1}{16} \int  \mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}} \, d\mu+4\int \mathbb{1}_{A_{4}} d\mu\tag1
$$
(you should have just one summation.) To arrive at (1) all you're doing is applying the theorem on linearity of integration:
$$
\int (af+bg)\,d\mu = a\int f\,d\mu + b\int g\,d\mu
$$
and applying it to a large but finite sum of functions. In this case the only functions in sight are the $\mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}}$ (64 of these) and $\mathbb{1}_{A_4}$; everything else is a scalar coefficient.

Comment: Thank you so much I see exactly what you mean..would that not also imply $$\int s_{4} d\mu=126 \, \mu(\{x:f(x)<4\})+4 \, \mu(\{x:f(x)\geq 4\})$$ is wrong though?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent That's right, according to (1) you need to calculate $\int \mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}}\,d\mu$ for each $i$, then multiply by $\frac{i-1}{16}$ before summing over $i$.

Comment: it'd be $$\mu(E_{n,i})=\frac{i-(i-1)}{2^{n}}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$ in the general case and then for this particular case, it'd be $$\mu(E_{4,i})=\frac{1}{16}$$, right?

Comment: Actually $\mu(E_{n,i})$ depends on what $f$ is, so it cannot be simplified. You don't need to work out the value of (1). I think the purpose of this exercise is to explicitly construct a sequence $s_n$ of simple functions that increase pointwise to $f$ (we're asuming $f$ is non-negative for now) . The integral of $f$ is then defined unambiguously as the limit of the integrals of the approximating simple functions. The only tricky part is showing that this construction works, i.e., convince yourself that for every $x$, the sequence $s_n(x)$ is truly non-decreasing and converges to $f(x)$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense..I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If your sets $E_{4,i}$ are disjoint then $\sum^{64}_{i=1} \mathbb{1}_{E_{4,i}}=\mathbb{1}_{\cup_{i=1}^{64}E_{4,i}}$